# Sequelize assocations

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and have been exploring associations. I am using mysql 5.6 and sequelize ^4.42.0. I'm trying to create two simple tables : PRJS & TASKS and insert some data into these tables.

Through the following code snippet, I am trying to insert data into the "PRJS" as well as "Tasks" table in one go.

But it just inserts the data into PRJS table although both the tables get created.

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const router = require("./routes/api-routes");
const sequelize = require("./config/db");
     const Prj = sequelize.define('prj', {
        id :{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        title: Sequelize.STRING,
        description: Sequelize.TEXT
      });

      const Task = sequelize.define('task', {
        details: Sequelize.STRING,

      });

      Prj.hasMany(Task);
      Task.belongsTo(Prj);

      Prj.create(
          {
              title:"a",
              description:"asdfasfasd",
              tasks:[{
                details:"asfasdfasd"
              }],
              include:[Task]
          }
      );
```

Following are the contents of the db.js file that I imported in the code above:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");


const sequelize = new Sequelize("test_db","test","123456",{
    dialect:"mysql",
    host:"localhost",
    port:3306
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lahiri

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 'as' when you create association.

```
Prj.hasMany(Task, { as: 'Tasks' });
Task.belongsTo(Prj);
```

2. The Include should look like this:

```
Prj.create(
          {
              title:"a",
              description:"asdfasfasd",
              tasks:[{
                details:"asfasdfasd"
              }],
              { 
                include: [{
                  model: Task,
                  as: 'Tasks'
                }]
              }
          }
      );
```

Try and write please what happens as a result.